# codeigniter field submit with field loop

Tags: codeigniter

How can I remove multiple fields from following code?

I use the code below, but I just need only handle single field (remove "[]"). How do I modify it?
        Model

```
$fields = array('title', 'url', 'shortdesc', 'longdesc', 'category_id');

foreach ($fields as $field)
{
  foreach ($_POST[$field] as $key => $value)
  {
    $data[$key][$field] = $value;
   }
}
foreach ($data as $values)
{
  $this->db->insert('table_name', $values);
}
```

View

```
  <form action="http://localhost/pages/edit" method="post" name="form">
   <p><label for='short'>Name</label><br/><input type="text" 
 name="title" 
  value=""  /></p>
  <p><label for='short'>Url</label><br/><input type="text" name="url" 
   value="ddd-df-adsfasd--asdf"  /></p>
  <p><label for='short'>Short Description</label><br/><textarea 
  name="shortdesc" cols="90" rows="12" id="short" size="40" ></textarea> 
  </p>
   <p><label for='long'>Long Description</label><br/><textarea 
   name="longdesc" cols="40" rows="5" id="long" ></textarea></p> 
    <input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="124" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"  />
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change next part:

```
foreach ($fields as $field)
{
  foreach ($_POST[$field] as $key => $value)
  {
    $data[$key][$field] = $value;
   }
}

foreach ($data as $values)
{
     $this->db->insert('table_name', $values);
}
```

on

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{ 
    foreach ($fields as $field)
    {  
        $key == $field ? $data[$field] = $value : null ; 
    }
}

$this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
```